# PHP include files from another multiple directory

Tags: php, html

*I know it is duplicate there are many questions as same.*

I have included in multiple files, I recently started a new directory and am unable to get some of my includes to work.

I want to include header.php in multiple directory's files but those link in header.php did not work in multiple files. you can see it in my code...

```
root
 |_admin
 |   |_user
 |   |   |__index.php
 |   |index.php
 |
 |_assets
 |    |_css/js/etc
 |
 |_includes
 |   |_header.php'
```

## header.php

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>AdminLTE 2 | Dashboard</title>
 <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,   user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
 <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- Font Awesome -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <!-- Theme style -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
 <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins. -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
 </head>
```

## admin/index.php

```
<?php  include_once __DIR__.'/../includes/header.php';?>
```

its working properly because one directory down.

## admin/user/index.php

```
<?php  include_once __DIR__.'/../includes/header.php';?>
```

its not working properly because two directory down. dont give me "../" or"../../" opinion i have already tried..

Comment: Did you try `../../` with or without `__DIR__`?

Comment: yes. I have tried both

Comment: Instead of relative paths, please use absolute paths. Define a base URL on the top and use it to include your files.

Comment: I've used these, header.php codes are included but their 'CSS, bootstrap' links not working for every directories

Comment: @AlokMali this is a good idea but I don't know how can I do it, I'm beginner still training.

Comment: set a constant in the top of the document like
<?php define('BASEURL', 'your domain or url which remains same'); ?>

and use this constant everywhere like
<?php  include_once BASEURL.'includes/header.php'; ?>

Comment: Why a leading `/` in `/../includes/header.php`. Wouldn't a simple `../includes/header.php` work? A leading `/` means 'absolute'...

Answer (score 0):

You would perhaps be better setting the include path initially and then using that in a more simple manner such as:

```
set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/' ); 


include 'header.php';
```

A similar thing with your css / javascript files - if you use the root relative path `/assets/file.css` etc then it will be available at whatever level of nesting you use.

---

In `header.php` change the css links to make them root relative links like so ( assuming directory structure within assets exists! )

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
```

At the beginning of any php enabled age that is to use the `header.php` file set the include_path

```
set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/' );
```

And then on the page that needs to use it

```
include 'header.php';
```

The css should be available to all pages in all directories if you apply that logic / approach.

Comment: it is still the same, header.php codes are included but their 'CSS, bootstrap' links not working for every directories.